AWS CDK selectSubnets function not returning all the available subnets
I'm developing a AWS application that has multiple stacks.
In my account I have a VPC with 2 subnets, each in different availability zones (one in AZ 'eu-central-1a' and the other one in 'eu-central-1b'). I can see those subnets from the console and using the CLI.
When I try to get those subnets from my CDK code I only get the subnet in AZ b. The subent in AZ a isn't there. I was using this code:
const subnetIDS = this.vpc.selectSubnets().subnetIds;
// subnetIDS = [ 'subnet-id-b' ]

If I filter by AZ as in the following code, the same happens. subentsA is an empty array. As I've said the subnet is there and I can see it using both the console and the CLI.
const subentsA = this.vpc.selectSubnets({ availabilityZones: [ 'eu-central-1a' ] }).subnetIds;
const subentsB = this.vpc.selectSubnets({ availabilityZones: [ 'eu-central-1b' ] }).subnetIds;
// subentsA = [ ]
// subentsB = [ 'subnet-id-b' ]

Does anyone know why this happens?

How is this.vpc instantiated in your stack?  vpc.fromLookup?  Do you have cached vpc values in cdk.context.json?
